# How can I restart gpg-agent?

Tags: services, gnupg, gpg-agent

Some changes in the GnuPG configuration demands a `gpg-agent` restart / reboot (according to the doc), but... How can I do that? I tried `gpg-agent restart`, `service gpg-agent restart`, but did not succeed.

Answer (score 221, accepted):

With current GPG (2.1+), to *stop* `gpg-agent` you can use `gpgconf --kill`, like this:

```
gpgconf --kill gpg-agent
```

You shouldn’t need to manually restart it. GPG will restart it when it’s needed.

This information can be found in [gpg-agent online manual](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT.html#Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT) and `man gpg-agent`.

Comment: There are cases where you want to start the agent manually, e.g. when you use it with ssh support enabled. The agent will NOT automatically start when you attempt an ssh login.

Comment: If you ever delete the `~/.gnupg` directory, you will need to restart the gpg agent manually.

Comment: You need to start gpg-agent manually if you want to use custom configuration that is not on the the default path.

Comment: Following "GPG will restart it when it’s needed": For me it was sufficent to run `gpg -K` (which just reads and prints the secret keys) to trigger the restart of the gpg-agent.

Comment: Late to the party but I often restart when I encrypt a file with symmetric encryption, beause it uncaches the passphrase and allows me to test-decrypt the file specifying the passphrase. Last I want is to find some time ago that the passphrase is wrong and that I `shred -u`'d the original file

Comment: gpgconf: invalid option "--kill"

Answer (score 54):

My preferred way is with `gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye`.
See `gpg-connect-agent help /bye` for a complete list of commands.

Answer (score 17):

On modern systemd-based Linux distros the `gpg-agent` is controlled by the userspace systemd.

You can check/start/stop it with the following commands (without sudo):

```
systemctl --user status gpg-agent
systemctl --user stop gpg-agent
systemctl --user start gpg-agent
```

Answer (score 13):

`gpg-agent` is not a system-wide service but started once per user (thus, it is not managed by `service`). Although sometimes invoked by user's dotfiles or at least in Debian and derivatives also when X11 is started (and `gpg-agent` is installed) in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/90gpg-agent` (to make sure a common `gpg-agent` is used by all GnuPG calls, no matter whether from a terminal or GUI applications); it is also started automatically by GnuPG when required. From `man gpg-agent`:

> The agent is automatically started on demand by gpg, gpgsm, gpgconf, or gpg-connect-
>   agent.  Thus there is no reason to start it manually.  In case you want to  use  the
>   included Secure Shell Agent you may start the agent using:
>
> ```
> gpg-connect-agent /bye
> ```

Usually, a simple `killall gpg-agent` (from a non-root shell) should be fine for terminating `gpg-agent`. You'll likely observe a slight delay when using GnuPG the next time, as `gpg-agent` is started again.

Comment: This changes in GPG 2.1.x and the process is handled through dirmngr.  The commands to run then are `dirmngr --shutdown` followed by `dirmngr --daemon` and sometimes additional options (I also include a specific GPG homedir and the `--use-tor` flag).

Answer (score 3):

In my experience there are some scenarios where gpg will
fail to start a fresh gpg agent (importing a new key?).

Kill the old agent as so:

```
GNUPGHOME="${GNUPGHOME:-$HOME/.gnupg}" gpgconf --kill gpg-agent
```

and then start the new one:

```
gpg-agent --homedir "${GNUPGHOME:-$HOME/.gnupg}" --daemon
```

Setting the --homedir explicitly when starting assures your ps listing
is clear when you have more than one homedir; and it's analagous to
what gpg does when it starts it.

Setting the GNUPGHOME when stopping is not necessary, but it might make
you or the code reviewer more comfortable.

Answer (score 3):

In my case `--kill` was an invalid argument for `gpgconf`. This worked:

```
killall gpg-agent || true
gpg-agent --daemon --use-standard-socket
```

Comment: --use-standard-socket is an obsolete option.

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions worked for me. So I just deleted the `/home/my_user/.gnupg` directory. Then ran my `bash_script.sh` (that contains the `gpg decrypt` command) which automatically re-created the `/home/my_user/.gnupg` directory and created `secring.gpg` and `pubring.gpg` within that directory.

Now, I just needed to import my keys like -

```
# importing public key
gpg --import my_public_key.pub

# importing private key
gpg --allow-secret-key-import --import my_private_key.private
```

Finally, I reran my `bash_script.sh` which showed me a GUI that prompted me for the passphrase to use my keys for file decryption.

Answer (score 1):

I face this problem too often and just restarting the agent works everytime.
For windows-

```
gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye
```

For Linux -

```
systemctl --user reload gpg-agent
```

Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

To add one more way of restarting the agent that hasn't been mentioned yet:

```bash
# kill the agent
gpg-connect-agent killagent /bye
# start it again
gpg-connect-agent /bye
```

If GPG caches SSH keys as well, the second command is necessary. Given that `gpg-connect-agent` is the recommended way of starting the agent (in `man gpg-agent`) I wanted to also use it for killing which turned out to be possible (at least with `gpg-connect-agent 2.4.4`).